# What the c++ standard says about loosing throw specifier in default destructor

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Three different compilers show three different behaviours compiling this code:

```
class MyException : public std::exception
{
 public:
  MyException(std::string str) : m_str(str) {}
  virtual const char * what() const throw () {return m_str.c_str(); }
 protected:
  std::string m_str;
};
```

Sun C++ 5.8 Patch 121017-22 2010/09/29: **Warning** Function MyException::~MyException() can throw only the exceptions thrown by the function std::exception::~exception() it overrides

g++ 3.4.3: **Error**  looser throw specifier for `virtual MyException::~MyException()'

Visual Studio 2005: **It is very happy** (neither error or warning)

```
class exception {
public:
  exception () throw();
  exception (const exception&) throw();
  exception& operator= (const exception&) throw();
  virtual ~exception() throw();
  virtual const char* what() const throw();
}
```

I know what the problem is and how I can fix it:

```
class MyException : public std::exception
{
 public:
  MyException(std::string str) : m_str(str) {}
  virtual const char * what() const throw () {return m_str.c_str(); }
  ~MyException() throw() {}  <------------ now it is fine!
 protected:
  std::string m_str;
};
```

**However I am wondering what the standard says in specific situation.**

I ran another small test in Visual Studio 2005 and I have found something that really surprise me:

```
struct Base
{
    virtual int foo() const throw() { return 5; }
};

struct Derived : public Base
{
    int foo() const { return 6; }
};

int main()
{
    Base* b = new Derived;
    std::cout << b->foo() << std::endl; //<-- this line print 6!!!
    delete b;
}
```

The signature of the two functions are different. How can this work? It seems that visual studio 2005 completely ignore the exception specification.

```
struct Base
{
    virtual int foo() const throw() { return 5; }
};

struct Derived : public Base
{
    int foo() { return 6; } // I have removed the const keyword 
                            // and the signature has changed
};

int main()
{
    Base* b = new Derived;
    std::cout << b->foo() << std::endl; // <-- this line print 5
    delete b;
}
```

**Is this c++ standard? Is there any magic flag to set?**

**What about VS2008 and VS2010?**

Comment: virtual int foo() const throw() and int foo() const both have the same signature, I believe - virtual and throw don't count.

Comment: To be honest exception specifications are generally considered a bad idea. They don't gain you anything, and if an exception that isn't listed is thrown then you whole program is crashed.

Comment: gcc 3.4 and vs2k5? If it is about standards compliant you should use at least gcc 4.5 and vs2010 to try out anything

Comment: One of the best treatments I've seen of C++98 exceptions is http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill22.htm

Comment: What 111111 said. Adding a specification does not make anything better, more efficient, or smaller. It adds extra code to call terminate. As such, they're pretty useless and better to just omit them. If you catch an exception, it's good, if you don't catch it, terminate will eventually be called anyway. About destructors, I am somewhat unsure what exactly is the problem. Destructors cannot (well, technically they _can_, but they really should not) throw. Destructors are called during unwinding, so if there is a chance a destructor throws, you're in real trouble.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your program is ill-formed as per the C++ Standard and hence demonstrates a behavior which cannot be explained within the realms of the C++ standard.

Reference:
C++03 Standard:

**15.4 Exception specifications   [except.spec]**

> **If a virtual function has an exception-specification, all declarations, including the definition, of any function that overrides that virtual function in any derived class shall only allow exceptions that are allowed by the exception-specificationof the base class virtual function.**
>
> [Example:

```
 struct B 
 {
    virtual void f() throw (int, double);
    virtual void g();
 };
 struct D: B 
 {
    void f(); // ill-formed
    void g() throw (int); // OK
 };
```

> The declaration of `D::f`  is ill-formed because it allows all exceptions, whereas `B::f` allows only `int` and `double`. ]

Comment: What about the default destructor? Does it implicitly have a "can throw any" specification unless explicitly overridden?

Comment: @MarkB: As mentioned in the above standard spec for a member function , I believe same would apply for an implicit default destructor & it will have a "can throw any" exception.In fact a little lookup tells me ,same is explicitly mentioned in `#15.4.13`.

Comment: @Als: Actually not. I think it was the case in C++03 but in C++11 for implicitly generated method the compiler is put to the task of generating the tighter exception specification it can (derived from those of the attributes).

Comment: @Als when you said: "Your program is ill-formed as per the C++ Standard and hence demonstrates a behavior which cannot be explained within the realms of the C++ standard." do you mean Undefined Behaviour?

Comment: The program is *ill-formed*, and the compiler *non-compliant*. The standard requires that a diagnostic is produced even if it accepts the code as an extension.

Comment: @AlessandroTeruzzi: I think that was an unlucky choice of words. When a program is *ill-formed* the compiler should reject it and thus there will be no *behavior*, undefined or not. An implementation is allowed to accept the code as an extension, but it should still *diagnose* (i.e. produce a warning) the issue. Additionally, if the compiler provided that as an extension, it should be documented, and I doubt that *compile but lead to undefined behavior* is a good selling point for an extension to the language...

Answer (score 5):

It evolved a bit in C++11 **[except.spec]**:

> **5/** If a virtual function has an exception-specification, all declarations, including the definition, of any function that overrides that virtual function in any derived class shall only allow exceptions that are allowed by the exception-specification of the base class virtual function.

So you are never actually allowed to specify a *looser* exception specification.

However this case is tricky because the destructor is actually synthetized by the compiler itself!

In C++03, I think the Standard was not so careful about those, and you had to write them yourself, in C++11 however we get:

> **14/** An implicitly declared special member function (Clause 12) shall have an exception-specification. If `f` is an implicitly declared default constructor, copy constructor, move constructor, destructor, copy assignment operator, or move assignment operator, its implicit exception-specification specifies the type-id `T` if and only
>   if `T` is allowed by the exception-specification of a function directly invoked by `f`’s implicit definition; `f` shall allow all exceptions if any function it directly invokes allows all exceptions, and `f` shall allow no exceptions if every function it directly invokes allows no exceptions.

Where the compiler will generate the exception specification of the destructor so that it matches what can be thrown from the functions it calls (ie, the destructors of the attributes). If those destructors do not throw, then it will generate a `noexcept` destructor which will satisfy the base class constraint.

*Note: VS2005 is one of the least Standard compliant compiler you might find on Earth.*

Comment: Should we interpret this to mean that a derived class and base class - neither of which specify what they throw - will generate the 'looser throw specifier' error in cases where the derived class happens to call the wrong functions?

Comment: @sage: I am unsure as to what you are asking. If you write a function and do not specify an exception specification then it is considered that this function may throw *anything*, and therefore an override cannot be looser.